# Python function os.path.exists() returns True when I give a bool value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to check a str whether file path or not, so i use `os.path.exists()`, but i put a bad argument, like this: `os.path.exists(False)`
then the function returns True to me, why?

```
import os
print(os.path.exists(True))
print(os.path.exists(False))
print(os.path.exists(1))
```

```
True
True
True
```

I expect the output of `False`, cause `True`, `False`, and `1` are not path names.

python3.7, centos 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from the [`os.path.exists` doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists):

> Changed in version 3.3: path can now be an integer: True is returned
> if it is an open file descriptor, False otherwise.

so it seems you have an open file descriptor for `0` (i.e. `False`) and `1` (i.e. `True`). That makes sense since those correspond to standard input (stdin) and standard output (stdout). You can also see `os.path.exists(2)` returns `True` since `2` corresponds to standard error (stderr).

Comment: Those file descriptors are almost always open, since they're stdin and stdout.

Comment: @Barmar oh, thanks. should have thought of that when i answered...

Comment: @hiro You can [edit] to add details :) I added it for you :)