# os.path.exists works with an integer

Tags: python

Today, I was writing a code that checks if a file exists before doing anything with it. To do so, I use

```
os.path.exists( filename )
```

By mistake, I gave to filename an integer value instead of a string value. E.g.

```
os.path.exists( 15 )
```

To my great surprise, it did not raised a TypeError but returned True (it actually returned True for any integer I tried).

Why does it work and what meaning this result have ?

Comment: It's right there in the first line of hte documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists "Return True if path refers to an existing path _or an open file descriptor_". File descriptors are integer values: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor

Comment: Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56358250/python-function-os-path-exists-retrun-true-when-i-give-a-bool-value)

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html)

> Changed in version 3.3: `path` can now be an integer: `True` is returned if it is an open file descriptor, `False` otherwise.

When I try it, it only returns `True` for a couple of low numbers:

```
>>> [os.path.exists(n) for n in range(50)]
[True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

Comment: How high should it be ? I tried all integers between 0 and 1 000 000 and it is still True. Also can I really have 1 000 000 open file descriptor ?

Comment: What OS? If you're on Windows, maybe there's a quirk there.

Comment: I am on ubuntu 18.04. (now I tried all integer between 0 and 10 000 000)

Comment: That's... very unusual, bordering on hard-to-believe. Look at `/proc/self/fd` to see which file descriptors actually exist for your current process.

Comment: @narsonalin As you can see from the example in my answer, I only get True for 0-2.

Comment: See https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c8c6113398ee9a7867fe9b08bc539cceb61e2aaa/Lib/genericpath.py#L16-L22 (genericpath.exists is what os.path.exists eventually calls through to). You'll see it looks at whether `os.stat()` throws an exception.

Comment: Oh man that's a *terrible* API decision. Not only does it introduce weak typing, it has completely different semantics for different input types. Do you happen to know the rationale? I thought it must be due to the underlying OS functions, but neither POSIX `stat` nor `access` (which is how you'd check file existence) have this behaviour. (EDIT: ah, it checks whether the underlying `stat` call succeeds at all, which it wouldn't for non-existent FDs. So yes, that's at least consistent with POSIX, though still bad UX).

Comment: @narsonalin, anyhow, I'm very curious exactly what `os.stat(99999)` returns for you.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Agreed. There's a whole bunch of [File Descriptor Operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#file-descriptor-operations), they could easily have added `os.fd_is_open(fd)` there.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Found the release notes. A whole bunch of functions were changed to allow an `fd` argument to prevent race conditions. But it seems misguided to include this function. See https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#os

Comment: Strangely, it works on my machine even though `os.path.exists in os.supports_fd` is False.